# How to install Shapely, but got stuck into Python language

Tags: qgis, python, gdal, mac, shapely

I have a MAC OSX 10.7.5 and am trying to learn how to use QGIS.
Following a couple of tutorials I came to know I have to install shapely.

I followed the instructions by the multi-cited http://tumblr.pauladamsmith.com, but I am afraid I did not understand neither how to start the installation.

I downloaded all the required files (i.e. GDAL 1.10 and its python package but did not move them in any particular directory - i.e. the complete GDAL framework seems to be installed into Library and the GDAL python package is still in the Download folder).

I did the following, thanks to the instructions of the link above:

```
MacBook-Pro-di-myname:Downloads myname$ cd /Users/myname/Downloads/GDAL-1.9.1 
MacBook-Pro-di-myname:GDAL-1.9.1 myname$ CFLAGS=`/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.10/Programs/gdal-config --cflags`
MacBook-Pro-di-myname:GDAL-1.9.1 myname$ LDFLAGS=`/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.10/Programs/gdal-config --libs` python setup.py install
```

but then that's what I get:

```
running install
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-3861.write-test'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or the distutils default setting) was:

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:

http://peak.telecommunity.com/EasyInstall.html

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.
```

Where is this error coming from? What I am getting wrong? Since this error impedes me   to continue I cannot follow the other instructions at the link above, so I am pretty stuck   with my work and cannot continue.

I will appreciate any type of help: I am totally ignorant on Python language and programming as a whole, indeed it was an unexpected problem during my QGIS learning.

Thanks a lot
Fra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Python default installer doing:

`sudo easy-install shapely`

You need write privileges to site-packages.

Other options:

1. Install homebrew and perform your GDAL / Python / Shapely installation through there.
2. Download the free (for academics?) version of Enthought Python.  I believe it ships with shapely.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I already have homebrew within my terminal app. I tried to reply the commands there but the answer is always the same as above..Sorry for being so hard to learn programming language.

Comment: @Francesco No worries.  We have all started in the same place and had the same issues getting rolling.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit more complicated. If you want to use Shapely with the QGIS version of [Kyng Chaos](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis), this QGIS version uses the default Apple Python (modules in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/), not the Homebrew version, nor the Enthought Python, nor...(the other options are invalid).

The solution is, as Jay Laura says opening the terminal in the shapely folder

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

sudo because each folder in Mac OS X has permissions and the command allows a user to run programs with the security privileges of another user (normally the superuser or root). You have not the permissions to alter the folder /Library/, it belongs to root

The final result is:

```
The C extension could not be compiled, speedups are not enabled.
Plain-Python installation succeeded.
```

and in the Python Shell (Terminal.app) or in the QGIS Python console:

```
>>> import shapely
>>> shapely.__version__
'1.2.17'
```

and you use the Plain-Python version of shapely without the speedups:

```
>>> import shapely.speedups
>>> print shapely.speedups.available
False
```

Why ?

If you do not know the UNIX part of MAC OS X and Python, it will difficult to understand.
The solution given by Paul Smith is specific, it allows you to install a Shapely version with speedups enabled (by the **GEOS C library** and not the GDAL library,unnecessary here). With a C file you need a C compiler (gcc or other) which is no more installed by default in Lion (yes in Snow Leopard), even with easy_install or pip, the two ways to install a Python module.

You only need to download and install the Command Line Tools available from withing **XCode**, You can get it freely (XCode) from App Store, look at the end of [command line tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-command-line-tools) or, easier, you can download/install the [OSX GCC Installer](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer) of kennethreitz (command line tools without XCode).

With the KyngChaos version of QGIS, this GEOS library is already installed in **/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/** (an the GDAL module in /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework) and the **flags**

```
LDFLAGS=`/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/unix/bin/geos-config --libs` 
CFLAGS=`/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/unix/bin/geos-config --cflags`
```

are only the paths of the C GEOS libraries in **/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/** used by the script setup.py and the **flags** (LDFLAGS = the folder lib and CFLAG, the folder include).

[image]

Once the compilers installed, you can install the shapely module with the solution given by Paul Smith and the result is:

```
>>> import shapely.speedups
>>> print shapely.speedups.available
True
```